# rsync include/exclude files with consecutive numbers in names

Tags: rsync, wildcards

I have files in the `src` `rsync` server like so:

```
p4.1

p4.2

p4.3
```

and so on up to `p4.67`.

Now I need to download some of them. Not all but from some starting one i.e. I wish to download from `p4.42` to `p4.67` and avoid downloading the first ones. This will be done by bash script which discovers what is current `dst` file number and provide starting number to `rsync`. The only solution that I see now is lame one with use of `--include-from=FILE` but it means that I will need to generate `FILE` by bash script and remove it from the drive after all. Wish to know if there is more effective and elegant solution with use of `rsync PATTERN`.

Comment: So you are trying to use `rsync` to copy files from that server to your local machine while excluding files with names like p4.44 and p4.88, yes? Do all of the files on the server follow that naming convention?

Comment: The file name convention is same on all machines. Actually I wish to copy files with names p.4.42-67 (then p.4.42, p.4.43, p.4.44 and so on up to p.4.67) but exclude the ones from the beginning like p.4.1, p.4.2 and so on up to p.4.41.

Comment: Is it p.4.42 or p4.42? If you just want to `rsync` 4.42 to 4.67 then a simple bracket expansion will do it for you and won't touch anything else.

Comment: Excuse me, I misspelled unnecessary dot after 'p'. What bracket expansion? Could you provide any example?

Comment: [Process substitution.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

Comment: @user1337 As you are trying to rsync, you have ssh access to the server and rw permissions to where the files are located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution of combining `seq` (generate ranges with chosen format `-f`) and `--include-from=-` (reading from `stdin`):

```
$ ls src/
p.4.31  p.4.32  p.4.42  p.4.45  p.4.46  p.4.54
$ ls dst
$ seq -f "p.4."%g 42 46 | rsync src/* dst/ --include-from=- --exclude=* -v
p.4.42
p.4.45
p.4.46

sent 183 bytes  received 86 bytes  538.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
$ ls dst/
p.4.42  p.4.45  p.4.46
```

Comment: Actually I used `Process Substitution` as @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams wrote in earlier comment instead of pipe  but with use there seq as @Yurij Goncharuk shown above. I'm not sure which solution is better - the `pipe` or `Process Substitution`?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle it is just to use *NUL-delimited* `printf` as follows:

`rsync -0 --include-from=<(printf 'p4.%d\0' {42..67}) .`